# getResources usage inside adapter class in android

Tags: java, android

I have adapted class like this

```
public class InboxAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<InboxAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = InboxAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<inbox> mInboxes;
    private Context context;
    public InboxAdapter(List<inbox> inboxes) {
        mInboxes = inboxes;
    }

    @Override
    public InboxAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_mail_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(InboxAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        inbox inbox = mInboxes.get(position);

        holder.tvIcon.setText(inbox.getName().substring(0,1).toUpperCase());
        holder.tvEmailSender.setText(inbox.getFrom());
        holder.tvEmailTitle.setText(inbox.getSubject());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mInboxes.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvIcon;
        public TextView tvEmailSender;
        public TextView tvEmailTitle;
        public TextView tvEmailDetails;
        public TextView tvEmailTime;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIcon);
            tvEmailSender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailSender);
            tvEmailTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailTitle);
            tvEmailDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailDetails);
            tvEmailTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailTime);
        }
    }


    private int getRandomMaterialColor(String typeColor) {
        int returnColor = Color.GRAY;
        int arrayId =getResources().getIdentifier("mdcolor_" + typeColor, "array", getPackageName());

        if (arrayId != 0) {
            TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(arrayId);
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors.length());
            returnColor = colors.getColor(index, Color.GRAY);
            colors.recycle();
        }
        return returnColor;
    }

}
```

Its working fine but I want set different color for my view holder text so I have added function in it called `getRandomMaterialColor`. But its using getResources inside it and I am not able to use getActivity. Anyone here can please help me for solve puzzle for me? Thanks!

Comment: Pass a `Resources` object into the `InboxAdapter` constructor, save it in a field, and then use the field elsewhere in the class when you need access to resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the view(itemView) in ViewHolder Class for get the resources, for example:

```
   private int getRandomMaterialColor(View view,String typeColor) {
    int returnColor = Color.GRAY;
    int arrayId =view.getResources().getIdentifier("mdcolor_" + typeColor, "array", getPackageName());

    if (arrayId != 0) {
        TypedArray colors = view.getResources().obtainTypedArray(arrayId);
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors.length());
        returnColor = colors.getColor(index, Color.GRAY);
        colors.recycle();
    }
    return returnColor;
}
```